# Make front end GUI for windows desktop app

Tags: python, user-interface, frontend

Im currently coding in python , and made 3 projects in tensorflow and openCV. The projects are pure python codes and I want to make a desktop app for them. I have no knowledge of coding frontend . I want some suggestions for framework I can use .

Answer (score 0):

you can check [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) or [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

You can also try making a server using Flask and serving the required service through websites.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no experience in front end, and don't want to waste too much time learning HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Bootstrapping, I would say that the easiest frameworks to use are [Streamlit](https://www.streamlit.io/) and [Dash](https://plotly.com/dash/), of those two I recommend to start with Streamlit, because you don't have to step out of Python, all you need to do is write a python script (*.py).

Toy example:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

st.title('My first app')
st.write("Here's our first attempt at using data to create a table:")
st.write(pd.DataFrame({
'first column': [1, 2, 3, 4],
'second column': [10, 20, 30, 40] 
}))
```

Then all you need to do is run the script by executing from the terminal:

```
streamlit run the_name_of_your_app.py
```

Behind the scenes this will create a development server on localhost for you to test and modify until you are happy with the app, after that you can deploy to the cloud either using Streamlit service [share.streamlit.io](http://share.streamlit.io), which I would argue is the easiest way to do it but is currently invite only (you have to request access to the service), or other alternatives are Heroku, AWS, GCP, Azure, etc.

If you want to see how this looks like here is a simple [streamlit app of a Keras CNN deployed on Heroku](https://cnn-cifar10-bts.herokuapp.com/), additionally on my github repo I have all the [code required to reproduce it](https://github.com/techno1731/Keras_CNN_Cifar10), in case you want some sort of template to modify to your needs.

Kind regards